# Iframe body when accessed through iframeElement.contentDocument.body is an empty node

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, same-origin-policy

I have a very simple setup on a dev server (both pages are on my local test server `localhost:5500`) where I have a main page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Example Mockup</title>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="./nested.html" id="frame"></iframe>
  <script>
    var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
    console.log(iframe.contentDocument.body);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and a nested page

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="hello">Hello, World</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

when I load the main page in my browser the output written to console is: `<body></body>`
I can access the element `#hello` using `iframe.contentDocument.getElementById('hello')` but I want the body element including child elements. Can anyone please explain to me why is this happening

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to wait until iframe loaded completely to access it's body.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');

iframe.onload = function () {
    console.log(iframe.contentDocument.body);
}
```

Comment: This will not trigger if the iframe is loaded before the script is executed

Comment: It can't happen since iframe content is loaded over a network request and the script is inline.

Comment: I would not bet on it.  It could come from cache and you could have more script executing before the onload statement